# Проблема при работе с русскими символами (wchar_t)

Tags: c++, macos

Я пытаюсь создать ассоциативный массив с русскими символами в качестве ключей. 
Например, мы вводим символ из консоли и хотим по нему найти поле в массиве. Однако, при попытке обнаружить символ 'б', считанный из стандартного потока при помощи **wcin**, мы получим **0**. Но при поиске по **L'б'** мы получаем успешный результат (т.е. **"ББББ"**).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    wchar_t c;
    map<wchar_t, const char*> alphabet = {
       {L'а', "АААА"},
       {L'б', "ББББ"}
    };
    wcin >> c; //Введем символ 'б'
    cout << alphabet.find(c) -> second << endl; //Напечатает: 0
    cout << alphabet.find(L'б') -> second << endl; //Напечатает: ББББ
    return 0;
}
```

Я пробовал заменить **wcin** на **wscanf(L"%lc", &c)**, но это не принесло результата. 
Помимо этого, я попробовал привести переменную **c** и символ **L'б'** к **int** и вот что получил:

```
cout << static_cast<int>(c) << " " << static_cast<int>(L'б') << endl;
//Вывод: 208 1073
```

Файл сохранен в  **UTF-8**. В терминале установлена та же самая кодировка. 
Операционная система Mac OS, компилятор g++.

Comment: так консоль вроде как не вайдовая. читайте уж сразу из файла. или вводите обычный чар через cin и преобразуйте его в вайдовый

Comment: *"сохранен в UTF-8. В терминале установлена та же самая кодировка"* - ну а зачем тогда читать в `wchar_t`? Если так необходимо работать с `wchar_t`, то сначала считывайте в utf8 в `char` / `char8_t`, а потом берите [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/home) и конвертируйте в utf16 или utf32

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Использовать можно потоки `cout` **XOR** `wcout` - одновременно они конфликтуют. Задавать нужно локаль. Буквы вы записали в `char` чтобы выводить в `cout`. Так как нужно выводить только в `wcout`, тогда нужно выводить **L"АААА"**. Не забывать нужно проверять успешность поиска  в **map**. Со всеми исправлениями вот что получилось:

```
// g++ -Wall -std=c++11 wcin.cpp -o wcin
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <locale>

using namespace std;

int main(){
  setlocale(LC_ALL,"");
    wchar_t c;
    map<wchar_t, const wchar_t * > alphabet = {
       {L'а', L"АААА"},
       {L'б', L"ББББ"}
    };
    wcin >> c; //Введем символ 'а'
    auto  it = alphabet.find(c);
    if(it == alphabet.end())
      wcout << L"1.Записи нет\n";
    else
      wcout << it -> second << endl; //Напечатает: АААА
    it = alphabet.find(L'б');  
    if(it == alphabet.end())  
      wcout << L"2.Записи нет\n";
    else
      wcout << it -> second << endl; //Напечатает: ББББ
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ! На Ubuntu всё прекрасно заработало. Почему не работает на Mac OS - тема для другого обсуждения.

Comment: **UPD:** я заменил wcin/wcout на wscanf/wprintf и все заработало на Mac OS

Comment: Я не смогу проверить, но кажется локаль  в операционке Mac OS не UTF-8. Попробуйте вручную задать в программе `setlocale(LC_ALL,"C.UTF-8");` и проверить wcout.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

int main(){
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
//дальше код, та строка меняет на кодировку на русскую
}
```

Насколько я понял нужно просто установить русскую кодировку.
Кстати можешь на ютубе найти канал SimpleCode. Там есть очень подробные уроки по C++, а также сейчас регулярно выходят уроки по C#.

Comment: Как этот канал относится к вопросу? Сейчас выглядит как реклама -- лучше убрать